# Are there any non-trival sequences which satisfy these conditions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $a_k$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k^3 = \cdots = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k^n < + \infty$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Are there any sequences other than $a_k = 0$ that satisfy this condition?

I suspect not, but I have not figured out how to show this.

Comment: $a_k = 1$ for finitely many $k$ and $a_k = 0$ otherwise provides more solutions.

Comment: The condition for powers $2$ and $4$ forces finitely many $a_k$ equal to $\pm 1$, and the rest $0$. The condition for power $1$ then forces them to be never $-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: This is just a side note... Does the condition for powers $2$ and $4$ really force $a_k = 0, \pm 1$? Why can't we take, say, $a_1 = 2$, giving us $a_1^2 = 4$ and $a_1^4 = 16$. Then set the next $N$ terms to some constant $c$ which satisfies $Nc^2 = Nc^4 + (16-4)$. (And all the remaining terms are zero.) This equation has real solutions for sufficiently large $N$. E.g. we can take $N = 1200$ and $c = \sqrt{1/2 + \sqrt{6}/5}$. Granted, this will only make the $\sum a^2$ and $\sum a^4$ series match.

Comment: @Bungo: You are probably right, $2$ and $4$ are not enough, I was thinking of integers. Making a sauce for squid that involves vermouth, and there is already more vermouth in me than on the squid.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: No point wasting too much vermouth on a squid :-) Seems to me that this method can be extended, so that we can make any finite collection of the sums match by constructing an appropriate sequence starting with, say, $a_n = 2$ followed by multiple constant sections. I doubt that we could extend this method to simultaneously handle all $n \in \mathbb N$, but it makes me wonder if there are other solutions besides finitely many $1$'s and the rest $0$'s. Interesting question!

Comment: There aren't. For example suppose that some $|a_i|$ is bigger than $1$. Then for suitable even $k$ the sum of the $k$-th powers is greater than the sum of the squares. So all the $|a_i|$ are $\le 1$. Then a similar argument shows that none of the $|a_i|$ can be strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: OK, that makes sense. If, say, $|a_1| > 1$ then the sum of the squares is $a_1^2 + c$ for some finite constant $c$. Then for even $k$, the sum of the $k$'th powers is at least $a_1^k$, so we just need to choose $k$ large enough that $a_1^k > a_1^2 + c$, which is always possible. Similar argument if $|a_1| < 1$. Thanks!

Comment: A better question might be if $a_k\ne a_{k+1}$.